# Localizing database data in jsf web application

Tags: database, jsf, localization, internationalization

I am working on a JSF 2.0 application linked to a MYSQL database. I need to present the application and data in multiple languages. Internationalizing the application was quiet simple using properties files for each language but for database, I don't know how to implement it.
Here is an example table(I won't include all fields for simplicity):

```
Tradeshows
id
place
date
description
posterUrl
```

All tradeshows should be presented to the user and I use a primefaces datagrid to do that. How can I show them in other languages?
I have thought of a separate table for each language like `Tradeshows_es`, `Tradeshows_en`, but I don't know how to load data from selected language table in JSF page.

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741718/internationalization-on-database-level) is of some help to you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design question regarding Java EE entity with multiple language support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499732/design-question-regarding-java-ee-entity-with-multiple-language-support)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I agree it seems the same as my problem. By the way, @BalusC your article 'Internationalization in JSF with UTF-8 encoded properties files' on jDevelopment helped me internationalize with UTF-8 encoding. Thanks for your great help online.